# Sweet Alert Javascript plugin issue

Tags: javascript, function, sweetalert

I am using [Sweet Aler](http://tristanedwards.me/sweetalert)t plugin on my site, to show a warning upon loading the page. It functioned properly when i used it once...

```
            swal({
                title: "Security Notice",
                text: "This site uses cookies to enhance your experience.\nBy continuing to use this site you are agreeing to the use of said cookies.\n\nPlease note; Your IP will also be recorded if you make a post.\nThis is for security measures only.",
                allowOutsideClick: "false",
                confirmButtonText: "Accept!"
            },
                function() {
                    $.cookie('allow_cookies', '1', { expires: 160, path: '/' });
                    });
                }
            );
```

This worked perfectly. But when i added another `swal` function it broke it. *but* the first alert still worked. This is the new code, the one that is causing trouble.

```
            swal({
                title: "Security Notice",
                text: "This site uses cookies to enhance your experience.\nBy continuing to use this site you are agreeing to the use of said cookies.\n\nPlease note; Your IP will also be recorded if you make a post.\nThis is for security measures only.",
                allowOutsideClick: "false",
                confirmButtonText: "Accept!"
            },
                function() {
                    $.cookie('allow_cookies', '1', { expires: 160, path: '/' });

                    //The following was added, which then caused trouble.

                    swal({
                        title: "Profanity Notice",
                        text: "The guestbook is open to public use,\nAnd so can be subject to obscene language and images.\n\n If you see such text/images, please report it to:\n<a href=\"mailto:abuse@my-coding.com?Subject=MyCoding%20Guestbook%20Abuse\" target=\"_top\">abuse@my-coding.com</a>",
                        allowOutsideClick: "false",
                        html: "true",
                        confirmButtonText: "Accept!"
                    }); //end of the new added code.

                }
            );
```

I'm hoping its something stupid, like missing out a semi-colon or parenthese, but i can't find anything myself.

Comment: What exactly goes wrong? Are there errors in the console?

Comment: In the first code it shows the security notice, and thats what its meant to do. But in the second code it shows the security notice, _but_ not the profanity notice, which it should. go [here](http://tristanedwards.me/sweetalert) to check the syntax.

Comment: Well, are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Well the first thing I'd try (not because I *know* it will work; it'd be an experiment) would be to wrap that second `swal()` call in a `setTimeout()` so that the alert code can clean up whatever it needs to clean up after the first call is done.

Comment: We are getting somewhere. It now shows the profanity notice, _but_ now the first notice doesn't show.

Comment: Hmm. Well I don't know anything about that tool. The behavior you're describing really doesn't make a lot of sense. You might try setting up a CodePen or jsfiddle to experiment.